# Can't get server status on an applet

Tags: java, swing, applet, network-programming, awt

im trying to display the server status green is on red is off. However i cant seem to make the applet change color!

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MinecraftPinger extends Applet {

    boolean O = true;

    public void Pinger() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        while (true) {
            Socket socket = SocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket();
            try {
                socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.148.1.1", 25565));
                socket.close();
                System.out.println(O);
                Thread.sleep(600000);
                repaint();
            } catch (ConnectException e) {
                O = false;
                repaint();
                Thread.sleep(600000);

            }
        }
    }//ends Pinger

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        try {
            if (O == true) {
                setSize(100, 25);
                setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            } else {
                setSize(100, 25);
                setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Fail!");

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code here; not on 3rd party sites.

Comment: I dont think your computers IP address is `192.148.1.1`, i think you confusing your computers ip with routers

Comment: that ip is a fake one to make the applet red but the applet wont turn red

Comment: Don't call blocking operations like `connect()` in the event thread, e.g. in `ActionListeners.` And if this code doesn't run in the event thread, don't call `repaint()` unless you *are* in the event thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your background isnt showing because you're overriding the paint method. Instead of setting the background color try using the `Graphics` object passed to you in the `paint` method

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    if (connectionWorked == true) {
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    } else {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

---

As EJP said you should never call blocking operations during the EDT. Put simply this means dont do operations that take a significant amount of time during the normal execution of your program (the interface/events thread). In your case don't query a server and block your applet from initializing and displaying. This can be avoided by using the following code:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         // do some heavy lifting here
    }
});
```

---

I dont see where `Pinger()` is ever called. When using the `Applet` class you need to overwrite the `init()` method for initializing data.

You might end up with something like this

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.net.SocketFactory;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MinecraftPinger extends Applet {

    private Boolean connectionWorked = null;
    private boolean pinging = false;

    @Override
    public void init() {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            pinging = true;
            startPinging();
        }
    });
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (connectionWorked == null) {
            g.drawString("Attempting Connection...", getWidth()/2-40, getHeight()/2-10);
        } else if (connectionWorked == true) {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }

    public void startPinging() {
        while (pinging) {
            try {
                Socket socket = SocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket();
                socket.setSoTimeout(2000);
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("mc.jujucraft.net", 25565));
                socket.close();
                connectionWorked = true;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                connectionWorked = false;
                Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```